# 640x480 resolution in grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my prebuilt HP PC, and grub's automatic resolution was 640x480. Then I went to edit the grub config file and set it to 1920x1080.
Even when i set it to that, it's still in 640x480. I've tried to download grub settings customizer, but it said its in 1920x1080.

Videoinfo only says 640x480. My other problem is that it wont shut down, I mean I need to turn off the computer manually, because it wont turn off. I say that because i think my problem is my motherboard since it's a prebuilt PC. (Btw. my BIOS is set to legacy mode, Windows is installed in legacy too so grub isn't in uefi) (Sorry for my english im Hungarian, i hope you can understand what i want to say)

Comment: Is the low resolution an issue? Grub is just used to select the OS. Try this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1628678

Comment: Yeah, i know, grub is just used for selecting an os. But i still dont like to have problems like that. I like when everything works fine without any issues.